# why it shows this error: Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `a'?

Tags: haskell

```
 agrupa::Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]

 agrupa [] = []
 agrupa (h:ts) =    if h== (head ts) then [[h:(head ts)]]
                    else []
```

---

Error:

---

it says * Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type`a' in head ts

what i dont get is that he is assuming head ts is [[a]] when its not , [h:(head ts ) ] = [a]

```
    7 |  if h== (head ts) then [[h:(head ts)]]
```

---

Note:
Ignore the else , just putted there [] to have something there

Comment: `h:(head ts)` does not make much sense, since both `h` and `head ts` are elements of the list.

Comment: but it shouldnt work?

Comment: Well `(:)` expects a head `a` and a tail `[a]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

```
h:(head ts)
```

Now the "cons" `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` takes an element (the "head"), and a list of elements (the "tail") and creates a list that starts with the head followed by the tail. But since `h` is an element of the list, and `head ts` is an element of the same list, they both have type `a`.

In case you want to construct a 2-item list, you can use:

```
[h, head ts]
```

instead. But that being said, this code is not correct and quite unsafe, because:

- it is not guaranteed that `ts` has a head: it can be the empty list `[]`;
- it is possible that there are three equal elements in the list.

A fix to solve the above issues is:

```
agrupa :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
agrupa [] = []
agrupa [x] = [[x]]
agrupa (x1:xs@(x2:_)) | x1 == x2 = (x1:y1) : yt
                      | otherwise = [x1] : ys
                      where ys@(y1:yt) = agrupa xs
```

The code works as follows: the first two cases are trivial: if we group an empty list, we obtain an empty list, and if we group a single element, we get a group with that single element.

The recursive cases is more complex. Here we inspect the first two items of the list `x1` and `x2`. In case the two are not equal (second guard), we thus construct a singleton group `[x1]` followed by grouping the rest of the list `agrupa xs`.

In case the two elements *are* equal, we again first perform recursion on the remaining of the list `(y1:yt) = agrupa xs` we know however that the first group `y1`, is the same group to which the `x1` value belongs, since otherwise `x1` should not be equal to `x2`. So we modify the first group by prepending `x1` to it. Returning `(x1:y1) : yt`.

This function produces:

```
*Main> agrupa [1,1,2,1,1,4,4,4,5]
[[1,1],[2],[1,1],[4,4,4],[5]]
```

This function can however still be improved, but I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: thx very much, i keep forgetting that : asks for a head and a tail